# Website URL's issue

Tags: magento2, url, multi-website

An issue has appeared suddenly with URL's on my site. I currently have the following configuration.

- AU Store (https://example.com.au/au/)
- US Store (https://example.com.au/us/)

However, if a user were to visit https://example.com.au the AU Store would load without redirecting to the /au/ URL.

I'm not sure why, however, this has now stopped functioning and a 404 error is returned if you visit https://example.com.au.

Is anyone able to assist in troubleshooting?

Comment: Have you set proper Base URL in core_config_data ?

Comment: The Base URL for the AU Store is set as https://example.com.au

Comment: Before where was redirected, when user was entered https://example.com.au ?

Comment: There was no redirect. https://example.com.au would load all content as per usual. Now I must enter https://example.com.au/au/ for the pages to load properly.